# Cordova 3.5, how to update local plugin?

Tags: android, cordova, plugins, plugman

I just created my first Cordova plugin and i would like to ask how can i reflect changes in files located in:

/app/plugins/org.cool.plugin

I changed content of plugin.xml file and I added some code in Java class.

After that i run **cordova build android** command but changes are not available in 
**platforms/android/src/...**

I would like to ask how can i force rebuild plugin, instead of the manual copy of files?

Many thanks for any help.

Comment: remove plugin and add it again using command line.ex for remove "cordova plugin rm org.apache.cordova.device" for add cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.device

Comment: Really is it too complicated? No quicker solution?

Comment: no,From what I know you remove them then add them - so 2 quick command lines (well, 2 per).